# Get handle by window class name of a external application and check if certain control exists in the gui

Tags: c#

Like the title says:

Is there any way of getting a handle of a unmanaged application by using the window ClassName and then check in the GUI of the application if a control with a certain name exists?

For example lets say there's a application named `"Math.exe"` which contains a control: textbox named `"value1.text"` and the window ClassName is `"math"`;

So I will get the handle to the application by using the name of the class which is `"math"` in my case and I will loop through the controls of the application if there's a control named `"value1.text"`.

What do I need in order to accomplish this task?

I'm **NOT** asking for the code just a basic explanation of what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to delve into the world of the Windows API. If I remember correctly you have to enumerate all the top-level windows to find the application you're after, then descend through its child windows to find the control.

Have a look at http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html for starters.